# Storm damage to tree

Tags: liability, trees

A storm broke a healthy branch which fell into neighbors backyard.  If I have this now damaged tree removed, am I admitting liability for neighbors cleanup?

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.

Many jurisdictions prohibit admission of evidence of subsequent remedial acts to show liability, although it could be admitted to show that it was possible to do something.

Also, the law of border trees is quite arcane and involved, and frequently subject to local ordinances, state laws, and common law rules all at once (and isn't terribly uniform from one place to another). But, usually, the bottom line for your liability to your neighbor will be whether you were negligent in maintaining the tree, which in the case of a healthy branch and an extraordinary storm, you usually would not be.